# dnu publish, The process cannot access the file

Tags: asp.net-core

When I publish my dnx web app via `dnu publish` to an IIS server, it works fine with a script that looks like this

```
dnu publish pathToLocalSource --out \\appserver\appuat --configuration DEBUG --no-source --runtime dnx-clr-win-x64.1.0.0-beta6
```

It works fine that is - until someone hits the website and then I can no longer publish due to a file lock

```
Microsoft .NET Development Utility CLR-x64-1.0.0-beta6-12256

Executing script 'prepare' in project.json
Copying to output path \\appserver\appuat
Using Package dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 6.0.0-beta6
Adding NuGet package C:\Users\[username]\.dnx\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc\6.0.0-
beta6\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.6.0.0-beta6.nupkg to \\appserver\appuat\approot\packages
Installing Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.6.0.0-beta6
System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file '\\appserver\appuat\approot\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc\6.0.0-b
eta6\lib\dnx451\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.dll' because it is being used by another pr
ocess.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, I
nt32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions o
ptions, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolea
n useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access,
FileShare share)
   at Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager.Publish.PublishOperations.ExtractFiles(
ZipArchive archive, String targetPath, Func`2 shouldInclude)
   at Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager.NuGetPackageUtils.ExtractPackage(String
 targetPath, FileStream stream)
   at Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager.NuGetPackageUtils.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.
<<InstallFromStream>b__0>d.MoveNext()
```

I can solve this by RDP'ing to the server and executing `iisreset`

What is the recommended way to get around this? Publish an `app_offline.htm` first?

Comment: I've got a script to publish an app_offline.htm (because by now it _is_ supported), but even that doesn't change the fact that myWebsite.exe is still locked and can't be accessed by dotnet publish.  :(  Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: no, only the `iisreset` hack

Comment: I finally got it working by just stopping the app pool, then doing the deploy, then restarting the app pool.  Seems rather ridiculous to have to do that, but app_offline.htm just didn't cut it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `app_offline.htm` isn't supported by dnx at this time ([issue #141](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/141)) and has no effect.
- [Issue #141](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/141) talks about using [WebDeploy to recycle the app pool](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee522997%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). I really dislike webdeploy's fiddly setup with magic local security policy incantations and hope to avoid it.

So since this is a UAT box and I can be loose with security settings, I added this to my deploy script:

`iisreset $targetMachine /restart`

where the executor of the script needs to be a local admin of `$targetMachine`.